# How could I align my label and textbox to the center? CSS

Tags: css

I currently have the following form

[image]

with the following CSS:

```
#myForm form {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  text-align: center;
}
#myForm label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  clear: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right; 
}
#myForm input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
#myForm select {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The html div sample:

```
<div id = "myForm">
        <form>
            <p> <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size=20 /></p>
            </p>
        </form>
```

How could I center my label and text boxes because it looks a bit off center. Additionally how could I make it so that the grey background is a box that is centered instead of taking the whole width of the screen.

Comment: please provide a fiddle and/or at least your html code also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css,  may be this can helpful for you and see fiddle link:

CSS:

```
label {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
p {
  float: none;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 50%;
}
form {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

SEE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8nNuH/44/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the box problem. I used the folowing css:

```
#myForm {
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "myForm">
        <form>
            <p> <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size=20 /></p>
            </p>
        </form>
</div>
```

***or just...***

```
<div id = "myForm">
        <form>
             Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size=20 />
        </form>
</div>
```

**CSS** (Remove all you wrote) **:**

```
#myForm{
    text-align:center;
}
```